# How to setup Reverse DNS in AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, cyber-panel

My domain is registered with GoDaddy. I have installed CyberPanel on AWS Lightsail server. Multiple websites are hosted successfully on same server. I am facing problem with domain email setup. I am able to receive emails but unable to send any.

Problem might be with Reverse DNS server. Don't know how to setup reverse DNS with this combination - GoDaddy, AWS Lightsail, Cyberpanel. Please Guide!

[Reverse DNS Lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABFce.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find the guide how to [Configuring reverse DNS for an email server on your Amazon Lightsail instance](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-configuring-reverse-dns)